# Display checkbox in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to ask that is it possible to display checkbox in result ?[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate?

Comment: As in query like "select * from 'table'" .It will display data in table formate, in this formate or in result i want to get checkbox in this.

Comment: SQL Server is a **database system** for storing, handling, retrieving data - it doesn't show UI's or anything...

Comment: An RDBMS (and SQL Server is the one) simply processes your queries, sometimes it returns some data. It doesn't *display* anything. An application does. If you really want to know about the checkbox, then your question is not about SQL Server. Please clarify and retag your question accordingly (while it's still not closed).

Comment: That would be the SQL Server **Management Studio** - but I'm afraid, that tool doesn't support displaying checkboxes either. You could search for an alternative to SSMS of which there are quite a few (Google or Bing for "SQL Server Query Tool" or something like that)

Answer (score 2):

No possible you can display 0 or 1.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can also return an empty string or an `x`. Still, that would not be a real checkbox, of course.